# Python fork and memory management issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to run some stress testes using python 3.6 on debian and fedora, I am trying to thrash the memory. I am trying a simple test as follows for now to get familiar with multiprocessing. The test is trivial it is litterally:

1. Allocating 2GB of memory in the main process with a bytearray
2. Spawning a new process and playing with the bytearray

   ```
   import time, os

   def f(name):
       print('hello', name, "my pid is", os.getpid(), "a[0] is",a[0])
       time.sleep(10)
       print("Finished pid =", os.getpid(), "a[0] is",a[0])

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       print('hello', "my pid is", os.getpid())
       a =bytearray(b'9'*2*1024**3)
       print("a values in main is", a[0])
       p = Process(target=f, args=('Child',))
       p.start()
       time.sleep(5)
       a[0]=54
       print("Main is terminated, a[0]=",a[0])
   ```

What I see is that memory is increased only 2GB and not 4GB as expected. When I try to modify the variable a[0], it is modified only in the main process, which is what I think is correct. What I don't really understand is why the memory is not going up 4 GB as the heap should be fully duplicated. Have you ever experimented issues like that?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: that's how virtual memory subsystems work; another good search term is "copy on write"

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!